# How to delete files from digital ocean via flutter

Tags: flutter, digital-ocean

I'm following this guide to delete files via `dospace` package: https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/uploading-file-to-digitalocean-spaces-in-flutter-827531d2cc06

After reviewing my code, I cannot figure out how to delete. It doesn't appear to be available for buckets. Does anyone have any insight into this?

[image]

Upload code looks like:

```
String etag = await spaces.bucket(project_name).uploadFile(
        folder_name + '/' + file_name,
        file,
        'text/plain',
        dospace.Permissions.public);
    print('upload: $etag');
```

Tried this so far:

```
spaces.httpClient.delete(Uri.parse(uploaded_file_url));
```

My XML returns: `"Code": "AccessDenied"`

My CORS settings:
[image]

My Files settings for the space:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the source code of the `spaces` package and it does not seem to have a `DELETE` method. however, I took a look at [the documentation on Digital Ocean](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#delete-an-object) and it seems you should be able to simply delete an object like

```dart
spaces.httpClient.delete(Uri.parse(uploaded_file_url));
```

the httpClient is returned by the `spaces` package and the `uploaded_file_url` format is supposed to be like

```
${BUCKET}.${REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com/${OBJECT_KEY}
```

you have that in your code as

```
String uploaded_file_url = "https://" +
            project_name +
            "." +
            region +
            ".digitaloceanspaces.com/" +
            folder_name +
            "/" +
            file_name;
```

Comment: Ahh makes sense, I'll give it a shot and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: That does not appear to be working, I've opened the permissions and it just doesn't delete.

Comment: `{
 "Error": {
  "Code": "AccessDenied",
  "BucketName": "myactualbucketname",
  "RequestId": "BLAH128-2bf111-nyc3c",
  "HostId": "2f01-nyc3c-nyc3-zg03"
 }
}`

Comment: This is nothing to do with the function, definitely a permission issue, perhaps your authorization token doesn't have enough permission. you should check that. Make sure the Curl in this example here https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#delete-an-object works with your token. and if so, then we can look at the code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my question with the CORS settings, I cannot seem to find any restrictions with the API key so far. I'll keep digging around

Comment: Should my url not have the full path? I'm currently using (example):  `https://myrealspacename.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/myspace/fbfdc9f4-4cb8-489f-8628-1dbf79cc64b4.mp4`

Comment: I think it should, based on this `${BUCKET}.${REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com/${OBJECT_KEY}`

Comment: I would recommend you to check this via Postman or Curl and if that's working then test in in Flutter.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this syntax correct for the CURL command

Comment: It appears that this package doesn't send a proper signed request. https://github.com/nbspou/dospace/issues/12  Do you know what this would look like with `amplify_storage_s3` instead? I heard these libs are similar and might be a solution

Comment: Oh I see, but don't you have access to `signRequest` function from spaces? if you have you can sign it yourself!

Comment: No you do not have it, https://github.com/nbspou/dospace/blob/970e4a8b7a5f2ebfb11f9401d80ef73adfa1188c/lib/src/dospace_client.dart#L77 it's protected.

Comment: I think you can fork this package and implement it yourself. that's very easy. you can reference to your github repo until they implement it.

Comment: Ya i tried that here, but running into an issue where I'm not sure what to sign it around line 47 with (`contentSha256` field): https://github.com/jpetro416/dospace/blob/master/lib/src/dospace_bucket.dart